# Using an Excel macro to save a file with the previous weekday date in the filename

Tags: excel, vba

I have created some code that currently works in saving a range in Excel and outputting it to word saving it with today's date minus 1 for the previous day in the filename.

However I'd like to know how I can change this code so on a Monday it will save it with the previous Friday's date, ultimately so that it will only use the current weekday minus 1 workday to save as the filename.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ActiveSheet

 Dim objWd As Object
 Set objWd = CreateObject("word.application")


Dim sPath As String

sPath = Environ("userprofile") & " "

objWd.Visible = True

Dim objDoc As Object
Set objDoc = objWd.Documents.Add

objDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = 0
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Range("B218:G246").Select
    Selection.Copy

  objDoc.Content.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 objDoc.SaveAs (sPath & "Report " & Format(Date - 1, "yyyy mm dd") & ".docx")

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line

```
objDoc.SaveAs (sPath & "Report " & Format(Date - 1, "yyyy mm dd") & ".docx")
```

with

```
Dim d As Date  
d = Date
If Weekday(d) = vbMonday Then   
   d = d - 3
Else 
   d = d - 1
End If 

objDoc.SaveAs (sPath & "Report " & Format(d, "yyyy mm dd") & ".docx")
```

Comment: I've updated my code, thank you, I guess I will find out Monday if it works!

Comment: There was a bug in my first version. Did you see it? ;-) I fixed it

Comment: I did wonder if 2 days would take me back to Friday from Monday, 3 looks much better, thanks :)